# strange jsoup behavior when getting first element

Tags: android, exception, jsoup

i'm new in using jsoup, so i don't know why follows appears:

```
...
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://4pda.ru").get();
Elements articleElems = doc.select("article.post");
for(Element article:articleElems)
{
    Element desc = article.select("div.description").first();
    Elements posts = desc.select("h1.list-post-title");
    Log.d(TAG,"size is "+posts.size()); // it's ok, size is 1
    ...
}
```

so, as size is 1 i wanna to get first Element, i change the code as follows:

```
for(Element article:articleElems)
{
     Element desc = article.select("div.description").first();
     Element post = desc.select("h1.list-post-title").first();
     Log.d(TAG,"post is "+post.toString()); // there NullPointerException throws
     ...
}
```

i cannot understand this...

Comment: Yes, that seems strange. Please add also the code for connecting to the source.

Comment: @F.Klein there is: `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://4pda.ru").get();
                    
                    Elements articleElems = doc.select("article.post");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting article that don't have `h1.list-post-title`
You can use `has()`. Here is the official doc about `has()`
`:has(seletor): find elements that contain elements matching the selector`

Here is the solution with has

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://4pda.ru").get();
    Elements articleElems = doc.select("article.post:has(h1.list-post-title)");
    for (Element article : articleElems) {
        Element desc = article.select("div.description").first();
        Element post = desc.select("h1.list-post-title").first();
        System.out.println(post);
    }
```